# Getting error while importing data from Mysql to hdfs using hadoop?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import data from Mysql to hdfs using hadoop, and also trying to create the table and databse is hive.I am trying with below command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/Mobile --username root --password 12345678 --table Accesories --target-dir /user/harsh/Mobile1 --fields-terminated-by "," --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table mob.cust
```

Mobile is my database and Accessories is my table which I am trying to import.Eveeything run successfully but getting error while trying to load data in hive.
But I am getting below error:

```
17/10/17 03:51:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/10/17 03:52:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 40% reduce 0%
17/10/17 03:52:48 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 60% reduce 0%
17/10/17 03:52:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/10/17 03:53:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1508188554902_0003 completed successfully
17/10/17 03:53:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=664170
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=521
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=88
        HDFS: Number of read operations=20
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=10
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=5
        Other local map tasks=5
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=398814
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=398814
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=398814
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=408385536
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=5
        Map output records=5
        Input split bytes=521
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=8631
        CPU time spent (ms)=11240
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=768512000
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=9839693824
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=448790528
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=88
17/10/17 03:53:16 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 88 bytes in 144.4472 seconds (0.6092 bytes/sec)
17/10/17 03:53:16 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 5 records.
Tue Oct 17 03:53:17 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
17/10/17 03:53:17 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `Accesories` AS t LIMIT 1
17/10/17 03:53:18 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive
17/10/17 03:55:10 INFO hive.HiveImport: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
17/10/17 03:55:10 INFO hive.HiveImport: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
17/10/17 03:55:10 INFO hive.HiveImport: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
17/10/17 03:55:10 INFO hive.HiveImport: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
17/10/17 03:55:10 INFO hive.HiveImport: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
17/10/17 03:55:13 INFO hive.HiveImport: 
17/10/17 03:55:13 INFO hive.HiveImport: Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     ... 8 more
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1627)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3317)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3356)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3336)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3590)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     ... 13 more
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1625)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     ... 22 more
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: Caused by: javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown obtaining schema column information from datastore
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: NestedThrowables:
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: java.sql.SQLException: Column name pattern can not be NULL or empty.
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:543)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:720)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:740)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setMetaStoreSchemaVersion(ObjectStore.java:7763)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7657)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7632)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:547)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:612)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:398)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6396)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     ... 27 more
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column name pattern can not be NULL or empty.
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:2074)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.BaseDatastoreAdapter.getColumns(BaseDatastoreAdapter.java:1575)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.refreshTableData(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:1103)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getRDBMSTableInfoForTable(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:1015)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getRDBMSTableInfoForTable(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:965)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.schema.RDBMSSchemaHandler.getSchemaData(RDBMSSchemaHandler.java:338)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getColumnInfoForTable(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2392)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.initializeColumnInfoFromDatastore(TableImpl.java:324)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.performTablesValidation(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3401)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2877)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:119)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.manageClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1608)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:671)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getPropertiesForGenerator(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2069)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getStrategyValue(AbstractStoreManager.java:1271)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3759)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.setIdentity(StateManagerImpl.java:2267)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.initialiseForPersistentNew(StateManagerImpl.java:484)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.initialiseForPersistentNew(StateManagerImpl.java:120)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.state.ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.newForPersistentNew(ObjectProviderFactoryImpl.java:218)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2078)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1922)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1777)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextThreadedImpl.java:217)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:715)
17/10/17 03:55:26 INFO hive.HiveImport:     ... 45 more
17/10/17 03:55:26 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:389)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:339)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:240)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:514)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Mysql version :  5.7.19-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 
Hive version : version 2
Hadoop version : 2.7.1

Comment: Based on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133156/sqoop-hive-exited-with-status-1) my guess is that you have issues with incompatibility between MySQL, Hadoop, and Hive.

Comment: Could you add the versions of each you are using?

Comment: added:    Mysql version : 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.17.04.1 Hive version : version 2 Hadoop version : 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to have been imported to hadoop system from mysql  successfully. So incompatibility is between hadoop and hive jar's. Log says, its a connectivity issue with hive metasotre. So, could you please validate the hive-common jar version in hive-site.xml and in hive lib?

Comment: version of hive-common jar in lib is 2.1.0 and I didnt specify any version of jar in site,xml

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I made sure I copied `hive-site.xml` to sqoop conf folder mine looks like this `/opt/sqoop/conf/`. Once I did that it worked!!!.